# How do I avoid typing password multiple times when using git?

Tags: git

I just started using git, I am using git clone to clone 100s of directories.
It prompts for password on each clone. how can I avoid this.

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Answer (score 3):

You need ssh-agent to avoid typing password of your private key each time it's accessed. See http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/openssh-key-management-p2.xml for details.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Git Credential Store](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) - this program will use the Windows Credential Store to store your git password.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SSH for authentication you can set up SSH private/public key pairs to do the authentication without a password:

General case: http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html

GitHub specific: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTTPS auth:

See the [guide](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)on GitHub. One-liner from it:

Mac: `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`

Linux: `git config --global credential.helper cache`

Comment: I am not using mac I am under the impression that this is specific to MACOSX, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The password caching is specific to github corrrect?

Comment: It's for HTTPS, if you are using SSH then see Jud's answer.